# Tkinter not refreshing on MacOs when writing to a Text

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

I have a small Tkinter app to show some serial communication.
It has two Text components (user_input and log) and a 'Send' button.

When 'Send' is pressed, whatever written in user_input is sent to the serial.

```
def send_clicked(self):
    data = self.user_input.get(1.0, END)[:-1] + '\0'
    self.serial.write(str(data))
    self.user_input.delete(1.0, END)
```

Also this method runs every 100 millis to display serial output in log Text component:

```
def read_serial(self):
    self.log.update()  # display input text
    self._read_character()
    self.after(100, self.read_serial)  # check serial again soon

def _read_character(self):
    c = self.serial.read()  # attempt to read a character from Serial
    # was anything read?
    while len(c) > 0:
        # get the buffer from outside of this function
        # check if character is a delimeter
        if c == '\r':
            c = ''  # don't want returns. chuck it
        if c == '\n':
            self.serial_buffer += "\n"  # add the newline to the buffer
            self.log.insert(END, self.serial_buffer)
            self.log.yview(END)
            self.serial_buffer = ""  # empty the buffer
        else:
            self.serial_buffer += c  # add to the buffer
        c = self.serial.read()
```

This works fine in windows, linux and mac.

Now I want to print ">> value" on the responses Text when the user clicks 'Send', so I redefine send_clicked:

```
def send_clicked(self):
    data = self.user_input.get(1.0, END)[:-1] + '\0'
    self.serial.write(str(data))
    self.log.insert(END, '>> %s\n' % data)
    self.log.yview(END)
    self.user_input.delete(1.0, END)
```

This causes the window to stop refreshing in MacOS (it works fine in linux and windows), I have to click outside the window and click back for it to refresh. Now I've aded a menu, I can also click a button in the menu to get an update.

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.update_idletasks()`? http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method

Comment: FWIW, instead of doing `...get(1.0, END)[:-1]` you can use `...get(1.0, "end-1c")`

Comment: @atlasologist, yes, on every component, with no success

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: @BryanOakley, no, I'm not using threads, should I?

Comment: @hithwen: should you? No.

Comment: @atlasologist I've observed that with update_idletasks it works better but still freezes when there's much output (with same output rate it works well in windows, for example)

Comment: How about calling only update() on the root?

Comment: @Lawrence, same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're running OSX 10.9 (Mavericks), it is likely that [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue19373) is the issue. I suggest updating your current version of Tcl/Tk or even updating to the latest version of Python (especially if you are still using 3.3). Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.6, I had python installed with macports in which py27-tkinter is a separate package so I removed macports python installation and reinstalled from official installer along with the activetcl package but the problem persits